# Divs not floating when content is too large

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to get two divs side by side.  The left one will have an image, and the right one will have some data.  I'd like the one on the right to just truncate when there's not enough room.  Unfortunately, instead of truncating, the whole div is just dropping down under the one that would otherwise be on the left when there's not enough room.  The picture below should make this clear.

Here's my html.  I'm throwing `overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap;` everywhere, to no avail.  When the content in the right div is not too large (or when I resize the popup wide enough) everything floats like I want it.

*(this is not MVC, if it was, I'd be using Ravor syntax with gusto)*

```
    <div id="tabInfo" class="tabDiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-info">Book Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-subjects">Related Subjects</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-info">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <img src="../books/covers/medium/<%= Book.medImgID %>.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px; font-size:10pt; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                <div style="font-size:14pt; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
                    <b><%= Book.Title %></b>
                </div>
                <div title='<%= PublisherDisplay %>' style='margin-top:5px; font-size:12pt'><%= PublisherDisplay %></div>

                <div style="margin-top:7px;">Author<%= Book.AuthorsArray.Length == 1 ? "" : "s" %></div>
                    <% foreach (string auth in Book.AuthorsArray) { %>
                        <div style="margin-left:10px;"><%= auth %></div>
                    <% } %>

                <div title='<%= Book.Pages ?? 0 %>' Pages' style='margin-top:6px;'><%= Book.Pages ?? 0 %> Pages</div>
                <div style="margin-top:5px; height:16px; margin-top:6px;">
                    <div style="vertical-align: middle; float: left;">Read?&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <img src='../Img/IsRead/<%= Book.IsRead ? "check" : "cross" %>.png' style='width: 16px; height: 16px;' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You don't actually have to use MVC to use the Razor syntax.

Can you set up a "working" sample on jsfiddle?

Comment: @Brother, based on other answers, it seems like there's no easy solution to get the divs to behave corrects, *and also* get them to resize with the popup window, so I just threw in some absolute positioning and now it's all as I wanted it; I was just trying for a cleaner solution

Comment: @Brother, more importantly, how easy is it to run Razor with web forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should* work if you just set a `max-width` property on the divs, so they can't exceed a set width.

---

You'll need to change this to work with your code; this is an example :)

```css
div.left
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

div.right
{
    margin-left: 110px;
}

div
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: @Philip and OP: So I guess the only way to get it to not drop down, **and also** resize as the popup window resizes would be to throw some absolute positioning on the divs?  I just did that, and it works, but now I feel a bit dirty...is there a cleaner way?

Comment: It gets a little messy, but bear with me. I'll update the answer, as it's easier with spacing :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to set fixed width for both left and right columns or the right column will goes down of the left one since it doesn't have enough space in the tab area. Thus, tab content area must be set width value as well.

You dont need to set white-space and text-overflow attributes

http://jsbin.com/uvibiz